# 401 Response in Anguar after appling Security in Spring Boot but not in Postman

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have applied spring security in Spring boot. My GET request is working and I add HttpHeaders.

```
get_Bike():Observable<Bike[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<Bike[]>(this.bikeurl,httpOptions);
  }
```

But same credentials is also used in POST , its shows 401 response. But in Postman it is working properly,

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup",httpOptions)
```

The JSON Structure:

```
{
    "username":"anjan",
    "password":"bolbona",
    "email":"anjanda@gmail.com"
}
```

Error :

```
 POST http://localhost:8080/api/signup 401
...
 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/signup", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: To have this question answered, you'll need to supply some more information. It looks like your signup endpoint requires authorisation first, which is likely not what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yaa, it is a signup endpoint and I authorised the endpoind . For that reason I send Httpsheaders .

Comment: You probably don't want to require authorisation on a signup endpoint.